# Common ways to target links?

Tags: html, css, href, target

Are iframes still widely in use today?

I am coding a site with `div`s, and I want everything to appear in the container `div`. Is it possible to do it without coding the `header` + `nav` into each page and have the content show at the exact same spot without using iframes?

I did a quick Google search and found a post that said it's not possible, but my site will have quite a bit of links.

As of right now, I am coding it with Tumblr, and the hashtags in the posts would act as links to a section of posts (Ex: `#blog` would retrieve every post under the "blog" link). What are some widely used ways to target links on a website?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a multi-page website, it would be helpful to have the HTML content be generated dynamically or be built statically from template files. You don't want to manually update the same content across multiple HTML files.

### Dynamic Pages

There are several options for dynamically generating HTML content depending on the software available to you. For example, PHP is a popular language for web development and is available through many web hosts.

### Static Pages

It is possible to build static HTML documents from templates using something like [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm interpreting what you mean by "coding it with Tumblr" correctly or not, but I think you mean you're making a Tumblr site with their built-in HTML editing capability.

I think you'll have a very difficult time achieving the behavior you desire there.  I think you're trying to create something resembling a [single-page application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application).  Tumblr probably just allows basic static HTML with little Javascript.  The suggestion Kyle made about using PHP or something like that won't work because that code must be executed on a server, and Tumblr doesn't provide that capability to my knowledge.

If you really want this kind of functionality, you probably should get some paid web hosting and develop your web development skills.  It's not a simple task, but it's fun!

Sorry if I underestimated you or anything.  Just trying to read between the lines.  It seems to me that you may be relatively new to web development given the content of your post, and I'm trying to nudge you in the right direction constructively.

Comment: Thanks, your comment was helpful. I first picked up web development when I was around 10 (I am far older than that now) and in between, I did stop for quite some time. I am reluctant on getting hosting at the moment, which I have in the past, because I wanted to see if Tumblr can integrate what I need for just merely a personal site. To say the least, HTML and CSS have both changed quite a bit since I last worked with it, so for the most part it's refreshing what I already know and learning the things that I don't.

Comment: Yes, things change very rapidly in web development.  Check out AngularJS if you're really curious about working on something like this.  There are sites out there that provide free web hosting (Github.io, for one).  With AngularJS and github.io you could create the page you're wanting without spending a dime.  It just wouldn't be on tumblr.com, but rather on <your github.com username>.github.io.

Comment: I don't mind it not being on Tumblr. I am actually kind of edging more towards paying for hosting at this point. I use sites like w3schools for information and it's great but I find that I want to learn more complex stuff, not an introduction I suppose. Which could be why I am struggling with this stuff now even though it all seems trivial.